# Bootstrap datpicker date is text get blank on second click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker. It's working fine on the first click on a date but when I click for the second time on the selected date, the input value becomes empty. Here is a jsFiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/technosml/xpvt214o/488158/.

I want one date to be selected every time. Even if I click on the selected date. I also want today's date always selected.

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <input class="date-input-read" id="start_date" type="text" name="start_date" value="9 July, 2018" readonly>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#start_date').datepicker({
      format: 'dd MM, yyyy',
      autoclose: true,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: According to its documentation, that's a feature of that particular library. However according to its [Github repo](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker), the entire thing is no longer developed and is actively deprecated. They suggest usnig this [new version](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) instead, which does not have this behaviour.

Comment: Thank @RoryMcCrossan its working now. I just update my css and js files to the latest version. Also updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working.

Comment: Here is my updated Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/technosml/n978kbdq/